# How does JButton implement its icons?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton

I'm trying to understand how Swings JButton/AbstractButton implements the painting of its icons (defaultIcon, disabledIcon, pressedIcon, etc.).

I have found the fields/getters/setters for said icons in AbstractButton, but apparently the assorted paint methods are inherited directly from JComponent. This begs the question how the icons are ever painted!? Obviously they are, but I could not find the code that does it.

Answer (score 3):

Paiting of components in Swing is made by the [Look-n-Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/). So if you want to find how the icon of a button is painted simply look the method `paintIcon` of the class `BasicButtonUI`. But each Look-n-Feel you use can provide different painting.

Answer (score 3):

The icon in JButton is painted by the UI Class. And the UI class is defined by the Look and Feel. It is an implementation of **javax.swing.plaf.ButtonUI**.

**JComponent.paint** method get the **ui** property from  the instance and invoke its **update** method (and is where the icon is painted). The UI of the instance is acquired by the UIManager

.

You can se the paint method on [Open JDK BasicButonUI](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicButtonUI.java#BasicButtonUI.paintIcon%28java.awt.Graphics%2Cjavax.swing.JComponent%2Cjava.awt.Rectangle%29)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question: are you trying to understand how does an icon get painted on an JButton? Take a look at the paint method from `JComponent` (its super super class). I'll add comments to make it easier to explain:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
     boolean shouldClearPaintFlags = false;

     //Check the size of the component: don't draw anything with a negative width or height!
     if ((getWidth() <= 0) || (getHeight() <= 0)) {
         return;
     }

     //Create new Graphics objects (why? to create the images)
     Graphics componentGraphics = getComponentGraphics(g);
     Graphics co = componentGraphics.create();

     try {
         RepaintManager repaintManager = RepaintManager.currentManager(this);
         //Initialize a RepaintManager (JavaDoc says: "This class manages repaint requests, allowing the number of repaints to be minimized")
         //Create a rectangle at the size of a graphics object
         Rectangle clipRect = co.getClipBounds();
         int clipX;
         int clipY;
         int clipW;
         int clipH;

         //If the rectangle is null, then give it default values
         if (clipRect == null) {
             clipX = clipY = 0;
             clipW = getWidth();
             clipH = getHeight();
         } else { //otherwise, use its coordinates
            clipX = clipRect.x;
            clipY = clipRect.y;
            clipW = clipRect.width;
            clipH = clipRect.height;
        }

        //Ajust the clip widths and heights
        if(clipW > getWidth()) {
            clipW = getWidth();
        }
        if(clipH > getHeight()) {
            clipH = getHeight();
        }
        //If your Component is placed on a JComponent (or extended class), then make adjustments
        if(getParent() != null && !(getParent() instanceof JComponent)) {
            adjustPaintFlags();
            shouldClearPaintFlags = true;
        }

        //Check if the component is printing (private flag IS_PRINTING)
        int bw,bh;
        boolean printing = getFlag(IS_PRINTING);

        //If the component is not printing its contents, and if the repain manager is double buffered, AND if not ancestor (subclass) is buffering AND if the components is buffered....
        //JavaDoc says for RepaintManager.isDoubleBufferingEnabled(): "Returns true if this RepaintManager is double buffered. The default value for this property may vary from platform to platform."
        if(!printing && repaintManager.isDoubleBufferingEnabled() &&
           !getFlag(ANCESTOR_USING_BUFFER) && isDoubleBuffered()) {
            //... then start painting the Graphics
            repaintManager.beginPaint();
            try {
                repaintManager.paint(this, this, co, clipX, clipY, clipW, clipH);
            } finally {
                repaintManager.endPaint();
            }
            //if there is an exception, a try/finally is required to avoid the RepaintManager being "left in a state in which the screen is not updated" (JavaDoc)
        }
        else {
            // Will ocassionaly happen in 1.2, especially when printing.
            if (clipRect == null) {
                co.setClip(clipX, clipY, clipW, clipH);
            }

            //Checks if the rectangle at the specified coordinates if obscured
            if (!rectangleIsObscured(clipX,clipY,clipW,clipH)) {
                //Then paint the graphics (or print if printing is true)
                if (!printing) {
                    paintComponent(co);
                    paintBorder(co);
                } else {
                    printComponent(co);
                    printBorder(co);
                }
            }

            //Also paint the children (eg: a JPanel has a JLabel and a JButton as children if you add them to the panel) (or print if printing is true)
            if (!printing) {
                paintChildren(co);
            } else {
                printChildren(co);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        //Clean up!!
        co.dispose();
        if(shouldClearPaintFlags) {
            setFlag(ANCESTOR_USING_BUFFER,false);
            setFlag(IS_PAINTING_TILE,false);
            setFlag(IS_PRINTING,false);
            setFlag(IS_PRINTING_ALL,false);
        }
    }
}
```

In other words, there is a lot of code involved in painting `Graphics` objects, but the steps are pretty simple once you've analyzed the code:

- Create new `Graphics` objects from the one passed in parameter;
- Initialize a RepaintManager for repaint requests;
- Check if the graphics can be painted, and do so if possible;
- Finalize by repainting the children;
- You're done!

If you want to know more on how the painting process is applied, then according to [Oracle's Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/summary.html):

- In Swing, painting begins with the paint method, which then invokes paintComponent, paintBorder, and paintChildren. The system will invoke this automatically when a component is first painted, is resized, or becomes exposed after being hidden by another window.
- Programatic repaints are accomplished by invoking a component's repaint method; do not invoke its paintComponent directly. Invoking repaint causes the painting subsystem to take the necessary steps to ensure that your paintComponent method is invoked at an appropriate time.
- You can invoke repaint multiple times from within the same event handler, but Swing will take that information and repaint the component in just one operation.
- For components with a UI Delegate, you should pass the Graphics paramater with the line super.paintComponent(g) as the first line of code in your paintComponent override. If you do not, then your component will be responsible for manually painting its background. You can experiment with this by commenting out that line and recompiling to see that the background is no longer painted.

I took the code from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JComponent.java#JComponent.rectangleIsObscured%28int%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29).
I hope I was able to help you,

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your comments in the code. This goes in the direction of my question, but still: How can the super-class (JComponent) know what Icons the sub-class (JButton) has and which of those should be painted right this moment (i.e. on hover, etc.)?

Comment: My guess is that when then the super class adds the sub class (eg; jpanel.add(jbutton);), it checks the sub class' graphics, and saves it in memory. The link http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/awt/Container.java#Container.addImpl%28java.awt.Component%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cint%29 shows how it works. Regarding when it's painted on the right moment, I am not sure, I'll have to look into it

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, I just added a few more explanations as to how the paint (and other derivatives) methods work. The text I post is taken straight from an example, please look at the link I provided for more details. Let me know if it makes more sense now!